# Sending the data through a post form serialization

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Im asking this question and hopefully can simplify it.

I have a custom field generator (using jquery) allowing a price to be set for a particular item. I need to post the values and insert them into a MySQL table row by row with the unique ID (x) as the relationship between drink names and drink prices.

my initial attempt was something on these lines

```
var max_fields      = 50; //maximum input boxes allowed
var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

var x = 1; //initlal text box count
$(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
e.preventDefault();
if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
x++; //text box increment
$(wrapper).append(''
+'<tr class="row_'+x+'">'
+'<td><select style="width:99%;" name="item[product]" ><?php echo $items;?></select></td>'
+'<td><input type="txt" name="item[price]"  class="input-small"><input type="hidden" name="item[id]"  class="input-small">'
+'<a href="#" class="remove_field pull-right"><span class="icon-cancel"></span></a>'
+'</td>'
+'</tr>');
}
});
```

when I post this to the server after serializing the inputs this is what is returned

```
print_r($_POST['item']);

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Boags Draught 24 375ml
            [1] => Carlton Draught or VB 10/375ml
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12.45
            [1] => 45.78
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 3
        )
)
```

How do i insert drinks and unique id into the table?

Comment: Your question is hard to understand. What is your input, and what should your output be?

Comment: Do you want to get only 2 & 3? Could you please explain what you desired?

Comment: I would like to insert rows for each drink and have that drink carry the id of 2 and 3 etc..

Im using a table where i store the data and extract where meta_id matches up to get the drink and price

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after our chat we came up with the solution. issue was how the OP was passing data to the server. we had to change the dynamic html input names to be uniform for each product like so

```
var max_fields = 50; //maximum input boxes allowed 
var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper 
var add_button = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID 

var x = 1; //initlal text box count 
$(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click 
    e.preventDefault(); 
    if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed 
        x++; //text box increment 
        $(wrapper).append('' 
        +'<tr class="row_'+x+'">' 
        +'<td><select style="width:99%;" name="item['+x+'][]" ><?php echo $items;?></select> </td>' 
        +'<td><input type="txt" name="item['+x+'][]" class="input-small"><input type="hidden" name="item['+x+'][]" value="'+x+'" >'
        +'<a href="#" class="remove_field pull-right"><span class="icon-cancel"></span></a>' 
        +'</td>' 
        +'</tr>'); 
    } 
});
```

then after serializing the form's parameters in the POST `$( "#form-package" ).serialize()` the data is sent in this format

```
Array
(
    [2] => Array
    (
        [0] => Boags Draught 24 375ml
        [1] => 12
        [2] => 2
    )
    [3] => Array
    (
        [0] => Carlton Draught or VB 10/375ml
        [1] => 90
        [2] => 3
    )
)
```

loop through it like this and you will have the correct solution

```
foreach($_POST['item'] as $data) { 
    $insert="INSERT INTO table (meta_id,meta_data) VALUES ('$data[2]','$data[0]')"; 
    $db->setQuery($insert); 
    $db->query(); 
}
```

Comment: thanks im checking this now. I have much more security in place. I just need to understand the logic. Thanks heaps for this.

Comment: am i supposed to this? $your_array = $_POST['item'];

Comment: @jonnypixel if the $_POST['item'] is that outer most array with the three arrays inside it then yes

Comment: im still not getting it - with that it wont insert now i this $your_array = array($_POST['item']); But i get the table rows with array[0] array[1] and array[2] in my table column for meta_data

Comment: The array comes from a print_r

Comment: @jonnypixel I'm not sure what the issue is. I edited with a way for you to test it. just paste into the code block and run that.. it echos out the id and name for each row. what is the print_r on? like what did you print_r() on?

Comment: i did it on $items = array();foreach($_POST['item'] as $data) {
 $items[] = $data;} print_r($items);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66375/discussion-between-jonnypixel-and-john-ruddell).